# I have a question about an integral of the fundamental thermodynamic law

Tags: thermodynamics

The differential form of the fundamental thermodynamic law is $dS = \frac{1}{T}dU - \frac{Y}{T}dX - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^v {\frac{{{\mu _j}}}{T}d{N_j}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaamizaiaadofacqGH9aqpdaWcaaqa
% aiaaigdaaeaacaWGubaaaiaadsgacaWGvbGaeyOeI0YaaSaaaeaaca
% WGzbaabaGaamivaaaacaWGKbGaamiwaiabgkHiTmaaqahabaWaaSaa
% aeaacqaH8oqBdaWgaaWcbaGaamOAaaqabaaakeaacaWGubaaaiaads
% gacaWGobWaaSbaaSqaaiaadQgaaeqaaaqaaiaadQgacqGH9aqpcaaI
% XaaabaGaamODaaqdcqGHris5aaaa!5880!
$ where Y and X are generalized force and displacement, respectively (ex: Y: pressure, X: volume), ${{\mu _j}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaeqiVd02aaSbaaSqaaiaadQgaaeqa
% aaaa!433F!
$ is the chemical potential, others variables are the following; S: entropy, U: internal energy, T: temperature, ${{N_j}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaamOtamaaBaaaleaacaWGQbaabeaa
% aaa!425C!
$: total number of j-th chemical species.

The textbook said that this differential results in $S = \frac{1}{T}U - \frac{Y}{T}X - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^v {\frac{{{\mu _j}}}{T}{N_j}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaam4uaiabg2da9maalaaabaGaaGym
% aaqaaiaadsfaaaGaamyvaiabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaamywaaqaaiaads
% faaaGaamiwaiabgkHiTmaaqahabaWaaSaaaeaacqaH8oqBdaWgaaWc
% baGaamOAaaqabaaakeaacaWGubaaaiaad6eadaWgaaWcbaGaamOAaa
% qabaaabaGaamOAaiabg2da9iaaigdaaeaacaWG2baaniabggHiLdaa
% aa!54DC!
$ or $TS = U - YX - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^v {{\mu _j}{N_j}} 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaamivaiaadofacqGH9aqpcaWGvbGa
% eyOeI0IaamywaiaadIfacqGHsisldaaeWbqaaiabeY7aTnaaBaaale
% aacaWGQbaabeaakiaad6eadaWgaaWcbaGaamOAaaqabaaabaGaamOA
% aiabg2da9iaaigdaaeaacaWG2baaniabggHiLdaaaa!523F!
$.

How it is done? I think it is done as long as intensive variables such as T, Y, and ${{\mu _j}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaeqiVd02aaSbaaSqaaiaadQgaaeqa
% aaaa!433F!
$ are constant. So..such an integrated form is only valid when intensive variables are constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume there is only one type of particle here for notational simplicity. Then the statement follows if the system is extensive, i.e. $S$, $U$ and $X$ are proportional to $N$. This then follows from Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions. You can derive this result by e.g. considering $U$ as a function of $X$, $S$ and $N$ and then considering an infinitesimal rescaling of the extensive parameters. We have:

$$U\left(S(1+\epsilon), X(1+\epsilon), N(1+\epsilon)\right) = U\left(S,X,N\right) + \epsilon S \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} + \epsilon X \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} + \epsilon N \frac{\partial U}{\partial N} +\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$

The partial derivatives on the right hand side can be read off from the Fundamental Thermodynamic Relation:

$$dU = T dS - Y dX + \mu dN$$

We thus have to first order in $\epsilon$:

$$U\left(S(1+\epsilon), X(1+\epsilon), N(1+\epsilon)\right) = U\left(S,X,N\right) + \epsilon T S  - \epsilon Y X \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} + \epsilon \mu N +\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\tag{1}$$

Since increasing the system size by a factor of $1+\epsilon$ in a proportionate way should have increased the internal energy by a factor of $1+\epsilon$ (here we're making the nontrivial assumption of extensivity, e.g. surface effects are ignored), we also have:

$$U\left(S(1+\epsilon), X(1+\epsilon), N(1+\epsilon)\right) = (1+\epsilon)U\left(S, X, N\right)\tag{2}$$

Equating the coefficient of $\epsilon$ in (1) and (2) yields the result:

$$U = T S - Y X + \mu N$$

Comment: I think your answer is the rigorous way to prove that (1) $TS = U - YX - \mathop \sum \limits_{j = 1}^v {\mu _j}{N_j}$ is made from (2) $dS = \frac{1}{T}dU - \frac{Y}{T}dX - \mathop \sum \limits_{j = 1}^v \frac{{{\mu _j}}}{T}d{N_j}$. But I still wonder the form similarity between these equations. So, I thought the following way (may be it is so naive): S is a function of extensive state variables, so the integral of (2) to get (1) should assume that intensive variables are constant. I'm not sure it would be another answer. Even if it is correct, I don't know what physics behind it.

Comment: @DonggyuJang  What you then get is that $S dT - X dY + Nd\mu = 0$, but this is then not a condition that has to be satisfied, it's a a thermodynamic identity that is then always true, it's called the Gibbs-Duhem relation. While you could say that if this identity is satisfied then you get to the integrated equation, but then you would make the underlying physics which is much more intuitive, totally obscure. The physics is simply that the internal energy of two cups of tea at the same temperature when mixed together will be the same as the sum of the internal energies of the two cups of tea.

Comment: And note here that this does imply some nontrivial restrictions on the interactions between the molecules, they have to be of short range. If we consider a gravitationally bound system, then it's not true that the internal energy of two blocks of matter joined together will be the same as the two blocks separately. Yet the equation $dU = T dS - P dV + \mu dN$ will still be valid, so the derivation that leads to $U = TS - P V + \mu N$ will have to fail, and it will fail the moment you invoke that scaling the system up by a factor $1+\epsilon$ should increase the internal energy by $1+\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Try it backwards and you see 
$$\mathrm d \left(TS \right)=\mathrm d \left(U -XY-... \right)\rightarrow S\mathrm dT+T \mathrm d S= \mathrm d U- X \mathrm dY- Y \mathrm dX+...$$
that your intuition is right.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, the fundamental thermodynamic law in the integrated form is valid for a reversible process of which the intensive state variables such as T, X, ${{\mu _j}}$ doesn't change. Can I ask further? In the integral, some constant C arises in general. Why is C zero in this case?

Comment: @DonggyuJang Would any energy offset matter?

Comment: This answer is wrong, the identity is a general relation that doesn't have anything to do with keeping intensive variables constant.

Comment: @CountIblis So you disagree that $d(TS)$ is $TdS+SdT$, interesting. Actually, I have more problems with your answer, starting from an infinitesimal variation, canceling the main part, i.e. $U(S,X,N)$, dividing by $\epsilon$ and concluding from the variation on the whole. Anyway, thanks for making the OP aware of taking the answer with care.

Comment: @CountIblis you might also have a look at [not the best source ever, but hey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy#Homogeneous_systems). Cheers

Comment: I don't disagree with the math, it's just totally irrelevant here. The Wiki article you quote only gives the result, not the derivation which is based on Euler's theorem on homogeneous functions. It states: "This result applies to homogeneous, macroscopic systems, but not to all thermodynamic systems."

Comment: @CountIblis My point is the following restricting myself to TS for now. And I do not care about thermodynamics here but math only. If dU=TdS it is dU/dS=T. Now integrating. int dU/dS dS = int T dS. say from S=0 to S0 and assuming U(S=0)=0 we have U(S0) -U(0)=U=what? If you want this to be TS, T  must be constant.

Comment: @CountIblis or in other words: if you write $\epsilon S \partial U/\partial S$ you mean $\mathrm{d}U/\mathrm{d}S\vert_{T,X,N_i}$, i.e. holding T etc constant.

Comment: U is considered as a function of the other 3 extensive variables S, X, and N. So, if we differentiate w.r.t. to, say S, we're holding X and N constant. In general, if we have a differentiable function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then in the expression $$df = \sum_j A_j dx_j$$ the $A_j$ are the partial derivatives of $f$ where all the $x_k$ for $k\neq j$ are kept constant. So, it's not (necessarily) true that $A_j$ is also going to be kept constant in that partial derivative.

Comment: If $f$ has the property that if all the $x_j$ are increased by some factor $\lambda$ that $f$ must also increase by a factor $\lambda$, then by putting $\lambda = 1+\epsilon$ and expanding to first order in $\epsilon$, you can derive that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \sum_j A_j x_j$. Now, you can also arrive at this result by considering a process where you increase the system size by adding a piece from another system at the same intensive parameters to it. That would be analogous to what you are thinking about, but that requires you to consider the Gibbs energy as a function of T, Y, and N.

Comment: @CountIblis Starting to become slightly philosophical.1:Holding something  constant or not is the difference between a partial and a total derivative. And what I especially mean is that you do not consider a $\partial U/\partial T \mathrm d T$--- while $U=TS+...$---for a reason. 2: So you are replacing one assumption by another one namely $T=$const by$ U( (1+\epsilon) X)=(1+\epsilon)U(X)$ mentioning yourself that this is not universal. 3: Finally, just out of curiosity, how does this increase practically look like, if not by adding something.